# Mail Session in a Singleton class

Tags: java, singleton, jakarta-mail

Storing the mail session (javax.mail.Session) in a singleton is a good practice? Me and my team decided to keep a single mail session in a static variable inside a Singleton class.

So, in the private constructor we do this:

```
try {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", config.getMailTransportProtocol());
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", config.getMailStarttlsEnable());
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", config.getMailHost());
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", config.getMailAuth());
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", config.getMailFrom());
        props.put("mail.debug", config.getMailDebug());
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", config.getMailPort());
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", config.getMailPort());
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", config.getMailSocketFactoryClass());
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", config.getMailSocketFactoryFallback());

        props.put("mail.pop3.host", config.getMailPop3Host());
        props.put("mail.store.protocol", config.getMailStoreProtocol());

        SimpleAuth auth = new SimpleAuth(config.getMailUser(), config.getMailPass());

        MailSession.session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        session.setDebug(config.getMailDebug());
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial MailSession creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
```

But I'm worried if is best keeping it like this or opening and closing a session for each e-mail.

Comment: regarding "singleton" + "good practice": Hover over the [singleton] tag and read the [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/singleton/info) text or [this](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) or watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you'll want to read this JavaMail FAQ entry on [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

And if you read the [javadocs for the Session.getDefaultInstance method](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Session.html#getDefaultInstance%28java.util.Properties,%20javax.mail.Authenticator%29), you'll see that JavaMail already maintains a singleton Session for you.  If you never change the configuration of the Session, this might work for you, although generally I recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather not go for this solution, since it can be cumbersome to share a mutable object among threads. Consider implementing a mail session factory from which you can obtain ready configured sessions. This does not imply to use a new session for each mail: If you are sending batches of mails  can send batches of mails reusing the same session.